# DAX when slicer is not selected show x when slicer is selected show y

Tags: powerbi, dax

Apologies for the vague title. I have two measures that i would like to display on a powerbi visual. Ideally when the report is not filtered according to any slicer it should display the Spend_plan_P0 and when the user filters on the region the visual should display the Spend Plan. Here's the dax query that I tried:

```
Spend Plan = IF(ISFILTERED(Query1[Reporting_Region]), refv_Spend_Cap[Spend Plan Region], refv_Spend_Cap[Spend Plan P0])
```

But it only displays only the one column irrespective of whether the filter is selected or not. Bear in mind in the dataset the Spend_plan_p0 doesnt have any regions linked to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are wanting to see. Are you expecting to see two columns for one measure?

Comment: No, when nothing is selected on the slicer it should show the refv_Spend_Cap[Spend Plan P0] and when you select a region on the slicer it should refv_Spend_Cap[Spend Plan Region]

Comment: So which one is it showing in both cases?

Comment: It was only showing the Spend Plan Region without any filters. I managed to get it to show the Spend Plan P0 if you filter on the region but only works when you select a single region. With Multiple regions it falls away and shows 0. Heres the code: IF(HASONEFILTER(Query1[Reporting_Region]), refv_Spend_Cap[Spend Plan Region], refv_Spend_Cap[Spend Plan P0]). If I can change that HASONEFILTER function to allow it to filter multiple items it should work

Comment: Is your slicer directly on the `Query1[Reporting_Region]` column? If not, then try using `ISCROSSFILTERED` instead of `ISFILTERED`.